# upload files to drive with python had import errors

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pydrive

I want to upload files to drive with python.
Now I am trying to use pydrive.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PYJDq.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cixwt.png)

I have tried
pip install drive
pip install pydrive --upgrade
pip install googletrans
pip install mtls`your text`

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

As per PyDrive documentation, I assume you have a typo and need "pydrive" instead of just "drive" in the first line of your code.

Docs: https://pythonhosted.org/PyDrive/quickstart.html

Code example:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth

gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.LocalWebserverAuth()
```